# Select Column value and append to column name

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

Is there a way to select values from my sqlite3 database table and append the corresponding column name to the value? I have more than 100 columns and I want it to return the value with the column name anytime it is called.

Comment: This part from API documentation could be modified to suit your needs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.row_factory

Comment: Thank you very much. I am trying to use the "conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row" syntax but when I call the keys function, it gives me an AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'. Please what may be the issue?